# Change object rotation at a frame does not work

Tags: modeling, animation

I wanted to script my object rotation during certain frames, but I realized that even by doing it in viewport, it does not work as expected. It always reverts back to its original state. Rotation works at frame 0 but not any other frame. Here is an [example](https://gyazo.com/372c472b838c10d89cb328a0a7e54f82).

Comment: might be the reason, that they are already keyframed. Another reason might be, that the object has rigid body....if that doesn't help, pls provide blend file

Answer (score 1):

Rigid bodies don’t change by keyframes, because Blender physics calculates rotation and position. You can either choose rigid body, or keyframed. But not both. You can change this behaviour by the "animated" checkbox in rigid body settings for each frame, if you want.

Comment: So there would be no way to have an object accelerate due to gravity, which is a part of blender physics, as well as rotate?

Comment: Of course you could. E.g. you could use forces to get a rotations. Or you animate rotation + position and then you use and keyframe „animated“.

Comment: I tried enabling animated, but it takes away the effect of gravity for me. Perhaps you can help with it? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y4a-Au0c_6l-jX-gq9anzyjTazzm_jVi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Another thing I'm trying is keyframing rotation individually and then keyframing position affected by gravity individually.

Comment: @Thomas0100: as i said: you have to decide whether you want physics (rigid body) OR animated (then you have to do all alone, even gravity), you cannot have both at the same time. But you can change the behaviour each frame.